# i have designed ui from pyqt designer now i want to connect that button and label together

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt, pyqt5, qt-designer

How define find Qlabel, Qpushbutton and QlineEdit to fix that attribute error?

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import sys

from PyQt5.uic import loadUiType

Ui, _ = loadUiType('tempconverter.ui')

class MainApp(QMainWindow , Ui):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.cal)

    def cal(self):
        temp = self.temp_in.text
        far=int(temp)*9/5+32
        self.answer.setText(str(far))

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainApp()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "d:/pythonproj/temp_test2.py", line 17, in cal
>       temp = self.temp_in.text
>   AttributeError: 'MainApp' object has no attribute 'temp_in'``

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow! Whenever you post an answer, consider including a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). In your case you didn't provide the "tempconverter.ui" code which seems to be essential to understand what's going on with your program. Please edit your answer and include it, so that we can try and help you with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should really consider posting the section from the .ui file where temp_in is defined, but I can see a couple of things wrong.

First, you have this line:

```
temp = self.temp_in.text
```

This should be:

```
temp = self.temp_in.text()
```

For QLineEdits to retrieve the text you need to run the function text() (it's not a parameter).

From the error message, it looks like you are using the wrong name for the QLineEdit. Is it possible that you are accidentally using the name for the QLabel?  What might be helpful is to run [pyuic5](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html) to convert the .ui file to Python code. This will let you use code completion to see what elements are defined within your IDE.